# Transparent background becomes black when changing from solid colour in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, headroom.js

I use [headroom.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/) to hide/show navbar on scroll. Works great. On scrolling up, nav has a solid background colour and when nav is at top, background should be transparent. No issues on Chrome but an issue with Safari.

**Markup:**

```
<header class="headroom navigation">
 <div> class="navigation__bg">...</div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.headroom--not-top {
  .navigation__bg {
    background-color: red;
  }
}

.headroom--pinned {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    .navigation__bg {
      background-color: transparent; // becomes black on Safari most times
    }
}

.headroom {
    will-change: transform;
    transition: transform .5s linear;
}
```

I cant see why the bg becomes black. Any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for starters you have

```
<div> class="navigation__bg">...</div>
```

it should be: (Closing too early)

```
<div class="navigation__bg">...</div>
```

Secondly set your

```
background-color: transparent;
```

to

```
background-color: white, rgba(255,255,255,0);
```

As transparent = black transparent (rgba(0,0,0,0)) in safari

Comment: Thanks for that but that never worked. I'll see if it's an issue with the make up and report back.

Comment: By bad, it was actually the markup! It was closing too early as you've said. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)